# BigQuery Join Takes Lot of Time

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to do a simple INNER JOIN on 2 BigQuery Tables and use the same to INSERT records in another table

The query is as follows:

```sql
INSERT INTO Table3 (EventDate, Opens_Count, Sends_Count, JobID)
SELECT
  o.EventDate,
  COUNT(o.JobID) AS Opens_Count,
  COUNT(s.JobID) AS Sends_Count,
  s.JobID
FROM Table1 o
INNER JOIN Table2 s
ON o.JobID = s.JobID
GROUP BY EventDate, JobID
```

This query is running since the last 1.5hrs and I'm not sure how much more time it will take.

Table1 has around 1.5million records and Table 2 has around 3.6million records.

Is there a way to make this run faster?

**EDIT 1**

[image]

Here is some log data that I can see

Comment: Do you know how much data is planned to be processed before running the query?

Comment: I'm not sure on the data to be processed. I suspect it would be in Millions as I expect the JobID's to match. 

I can see some logs which I will add in the question as an edit

Comment: If you open the query in a new browser tab *before hitting run*, there is an information on the right upper side about the amount of TB being processed. Be careful of your Google Cloud Billing as well! 1.5 hours looks a lot.

You could also debug by adding a `WHERE` clause with `EventDate` from yesterday only and then extrapolate with the number of days to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```sql
COUNT(o.JobID) AS Opens_Count,
COUNT(s.JobID) AS Sends_Count,
```

by

```sql
COUNT(*) AS Sends_Count
```

Your request with `INNER JOIN` will only count the intersection of the two tables. I would do a `RIGHT JOIN` to measure the open rate for the messages

```sql
FROM Table1 o
RIGHT JOIN Table2 s
ON o.JobID = s.JobID
```

and then counting the non null rows for `o.EventDate` versus the total number of rows.

Comment: Thanks MIchel for the explanation. Got your point. I'll replace the count(jobid) by count(*) and check. I think it makes more sense  as I have already done a group by on jobid and date so count(*) should give the desired count anyways

but here I have 2 tables. How do i get diff counts for both. like count(table1) and count(table2)? I have replaced count(o.JobID) and count(s.JobID) with count(o) and count(s)

Comment: With the `RIGHT JOIN` technique, `COUNTIF(o.EventDate IS NULL) AS Opens_Count`, the number of messages that were sent but never opened.

`COUNT(*) AS Sends_Count`, the number of messages that were sent.

Comment: how much was the amount of TB processed ?